# Having problems to access Firebase Overview/Features

Tags: firebase

I am having problems to access Firebase Page.

I have multi google accounts and they were all connected at same time.

I have the firebase only registered in one of them and everysingle time I try to access firebase the first account that shows up as current is one that I am not registered with and not even logged in anymore.

Then when I change to the right one I can't access the features. The overview is completely different like it was reset or I just created an account. And I can't access anything.

It looks like a problem with multi google account and firebase.

Does anyone have the same? Is there a way to fix it?

I already logged out all my other accounts.

Comment: Can you try logging in in a Chrome incognito window, turning off all extensions, and see if it works? If you're still having trouble, you can [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) and provide screenshots as well as information about the browser and version of browser you're using.

Comment: I did send them information about my problem. With the incognito mode works fine. I don't know why. But I would like to solve this problem definitively. Thank you.